# How do i make this if-then statement work

Tags: python, if-statement

I am currently learning python and i cant seen to figure out how to get a if - then statement for a dice to work (randomint).

I tried

```
if roll_dice < 10:
  print ("dang, you got a low roll, try again")
else:
  roll_dice > 10
  print ("nice! you got a high roll")
  roll_dice = 10
  print ("10!")
```

It says "ValueError: don't know how to compare 'function' and 'int' "

Comment: You could also define roll_dice as a random int for testing: roll_dice = random.randint(1, 10). Also, based off that error you aren't sharing all of your relevant code. Is your function named roll_dice?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want it to work this way:

```
if roll_dice < 10:
  print ("dang, you got a low roll, try again")
elif roll_dice > 10:
  print ("nice! you got a high roll")
else:
  print ("10!")
```

or

```
if roll_dice < 10:
  print ("dang, you got a low roll, try again")
elif roll_dice > 10:
  print ("nice! you got a high roll")
elif roll_dice == 10:
  print ("10!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `roll_dice` is a function, so you need to call it to get an answer, so `roll_dice < 10` is meaningless. It would be like asking `print < 10` or `abs < 10`.

Try this:

```
roll = roll_dice()
if roll < 10:
    print("dang, you got a low roll, try again")
elif roll > 10:
    print ("nice! you got a high roll")
else:
    assert(roll == 10)
    print("10!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are feeding your variable (roll_dice). But if it's through a keyboard input you can do this.

[Code to look at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvNYK.png)

Remember also to compare a roll_dice >10.

You have to do this int(roll_dice).

It changes it from string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of the code in one line - using the ternary operator.  This sort of coding is not advised, but illustrates another way of coding this.

```
print ("dang, you got a low roll, try again" if roll_dice < 10 else "nice! you got a high roll" if roll_dice > 10 else "10!" )
```

The real issue with the original question is that the syntax of the `if` statement is incorrect.